# How to change a pausable token-

Tags: tokens

i AM not a developer. Some time ago i asked somebody to create POLONICO token for our streaming media POLONICO TV. MintMe does not support pausable tokens - a lnybody can help me to convert them? sorry to be such a nut. Anira wojan

Comment: Elo Elo Every body - i am very grateful for both answers and of course I do accept the offer to help me with gratitude - should i give the entrance codes here?

Answer (score 0):

In your etherscan token
you should go to this page
https://etherscan.io/token/0x6c5507469429b90Bea016935A4FDc1Cc23fca6Ed#writeContract

connect with your wallet in the button "connect to web3"

after that, just go to the 8th button in the list that says "Pause", press it, accept the transaction in your wallet and that's it.

Comment: 0x4ddddd9a7f0b2da539017c59165a5bd5640e7ad7 is admin

Etherscan entrance:
l:FundacjaKossakowskiego 

p: Charbel23

(email token@polonico.com)

Comment: 0x4ddddd9a7f0b2da539017c59165a5bd5640e7ad7 is admin

Etherscan entrance:
l:FundacjaKossakowskiego 

p: Charbel23

(email token@polonico.com)

Comment: i will gry on Monday when i will come back to my walory and them i will  help you if i succeed

Comment: And what if youmake yourself the admin and maks it with your walory? Os this to much to ask?

Comment: Do not do this, NEVER share admin rights or keys  with people you don't know. Either try doing it yourself or hire a professional you know.

Comment: i know that tyle, but somehow i trust  ok - i will do it myself- thank you obce again

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are referring to this token: https://etherscan.io/token/0x6c5507469429b90Bea016935A4FDc1Cc23fca6Ed#readContract

Then in order to pause the contract, you only need to call the pause() function, which is under writeContract tab, using one of the admin's accounts that have the pauser role. You can check if your account has the appropriate role using hasRole under readContract tab.

Comment: Thank you for hour kind reply. VASIK offered me to help with that issue. I will gry to roll those tokens to the world. i can see at your profile that you are great counceler. I am streaming FAST TV ( www.gama.international) If you find it interesting - we can  set a zoom. i am trying to enter with these tokens for 2 years, but never nad a budget...but TVs are browning,we are event organizmy a budget mediatorem im Polan mediaforumkrynica.pl